# my tableView can't get the list

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, afnetworking-3

Can any one check with me this code i can't get json item in my table view, i only get them on the Xcode console and i can't find the error.
………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………...

```
/*
static NSString * const BaseURLStringg = @"http://api-     public.guidebox.com/v1.43/Tunisia/rKgEWJbFg0kgEHrcGXPKhPDo0XtTafyC/movies  /all/250/250";
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,      UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableData;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tab;
*/         

@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLStringg];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];    
[manager GET:url.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable   responseObject) {        
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
    NSArray *products = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"];
    [products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj,NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){            
        NSString *title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [obj objectForKey:@"title"] ];
        NSString *release_year = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [obj objectForKey:@"release_year"] ];
        NSString *themoviedb= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [obj objectForKey:@"themoviedb"] ];
        NSString *original_title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [obj objectForKey:@"original_title"] ];                                 
        [_tab clearsContextBeforeDrawing];
        [_tableData insertObject:title atIndex:0];
        [_tableData insertObject:release_year atIndex:1];
        [_tableData insertObject:themoviedb atIndex:2];
        [_tableData insertObject:original_title atIndex:3];                                             
    }];        //[self tableData];
    // [_tableData addObject:@"gggggggg"];                
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //self.tableData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:responseObject];
        [self.tab reloadData];
    });                
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {       
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);        
}];        
}
  -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:       (NSInteger)section{
    return [self.tableData count];
 }
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    
      UITableViewCell* mycell=[tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];   
     // NSInteger nameindex=[_DB.arrColumnNames   indexOfObject:@"name"];    
     //NSString* name=[[_myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:nameindex];    
if (_tableData!=nil){        
    UILabel *title = [mycell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    UILabel *release_year = [mycell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
    UILabel *themoviedb = [mycell.contentView viewWithTag:103];
    UILabel *original_title = [mycell.contentView viewWithTag:104];                
    title.text= [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    release_year.text= [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    themoviedb.text= [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    original_title.text= [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
}
//mycell.textLabel.text=@"eererr";
mycell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];            
mycell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
mycell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
return mycell;
 }
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{        
 }
 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
 @end
```

Comment: Is `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` getting called?

Comment: yes i think yes … i'm beginner friend so ….

Comment: AdamPro13 can u check with please this code

Comment: so where did you instantiate _tableData?

Comment: in mu viewController.h

Comment: Try add debug at line `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //self.tableData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:responseObject];
        [self.tab reloadData];
    });   `
and line `if (_tableData!=nil){   ` to take care about your array data

Comment: i have do it but nothing changed the same problem

Comment: @WassimBenHamida what? instantiate your _tableData in the headerfile?

Comment: yes i have do it  @Joshua but nothing change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the data like so:

```
        [_tableData insertObject:title atIndex:0];
        [_tableData insertObject:release_year atIndex:1];
        [_tableData insertObject:themoviedb atIndex:2];
        [_tableData insertObject:original_title atIndex:3];
```

But you are reading out the data like:

```
        title.text= [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        release_year.text= [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        themoviedb.text= [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        original_title.text= [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

indexPath.row will be the same integer (e.g. for the first cell in the section it will be 0). So for that cell the title will be set to `title.text`, `release_year.text`, `themoviedb.text`, and `original_title.text`. This is not what you intend. You should use an NSDictionary and add that to self.tableData. For example you should replace the first bit of code with:

```
        NSDictionary *movieDictionary = @{@"title":title,@"release_year":release_year,@"themoviedb":themoviedb,@"original_title":original_title};
        [self.tableData addObject:movieDictionary];
```

The in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
        NSDictionary *movieDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
        title.text= movieDictionary[@"title"];
        release_year.text= movieDictionary[@"release_year"];
        themoviedb.text= movieDictionary[@"themoviedb"];
        original_title.text= movieDictionary[@"original_title"];
```

Comment: Add an NSLog to cellForRowAtIndexPath so you can answer AdamPro13's question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't read all code, but this line I think may be wrong.

```
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //self.tableData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:responseObject];
        [self.tab reloadData];
    });
```

GCD write like this , will lock main thread, then UI refresh will not execute, if you want to `reloadData`, you need write like below

```
    dispatch_asyn(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //self.tableData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:responseObject];
        [self.tab reloadData];
    });
```

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this type of code code

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.androidhive.info/songs/albums.php"];
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
        [manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
            cource_data=[responseObject valueForKey:@"name"];
             NSLog(@"JSON: %@", cource_data);
            [self.tbl_cource reloadData];
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
   }];
```